# Multiple lines in bootstrap navbar

Tags: bootstrap-vue

I am using bootstrap-vue. I try to convert existing header to the navbar. There shall be a big brand name and a smaller slogan under it. I tried to use H1 and b-nav-text with BR but both texts are always rendered side by side. How can I place the slogan below the brand title?

```
    <b-navbar-brand href="/">
      <img src="./assets/logo.png" :alt="$t('app.logo-alt')"  class="d-inline-block align-top">
    </b-navbar-brand>

    <b-navbar-toggle target="nav-collapse"></b-navbar-toggle>
    <b-collapse id="nav-collapse" is-nav>
      <b-navbar-nav>
        <b-nav-text class="text-white">{{ $t('app.name') }}</b-nav-text>
        <br>
        <b-nav-text class="text-white">{{ $t('app.slogan') }}</b-nav-text>
      </b-navbar-nav>
```

The upper side of picture is b-nav output, the below is original header built with b-container.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> d-inline-flex   flex-column

```
<b-navbar-toggle target="nav-collapse"></b-navbar-toggle>
<b-collapse id="nav-collapse" is-nav>
  <b-navbar-nav>
    <b-nav-text class="d-inline-flex flex-column">
      <span>Lorem ipsum is placeholder text commonly used in</span>
      <span>the graphic, print</span>
      </span>
    </b-nav-text>
  </b-navbar-nav>
```